# How do I use 'if' statements in R to manipulate a dataset using a range of possible values?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am working with a dataset (titled "AvianFatalities") in R investigating avian fatalities at a wind power plant, and I'm asking the question of what makes a bird more or less likely to collide with a wind turbine. The dataset I have was collected by individuals at the facility on specific days on which an individual searched a series of turbines for the presence or absence of a carcass. The individual annotated the day of the month the survey was done ("Day" range: 1-31), and the estimated number of days the bird had been dead ("DaysDead" range: 2-60). If no bird was found, the "DaysDead" data point is an 'NA'.

This dataset tells me the day and month ("Month" range: 1-12) in which a carcass was found, but I need an estimation of the month in which the bird actually hit the turbine, so I created a new column for the corrected month (titled "CorrMonth") using the following code:

```
AvianFatalities$CorrMonth<-NA
```

I now have a column for corrected month, and I know I should be able to use some combination of code to fill in that column with the correct information such that:

> If "Day"-"DaysDead" = -1 through -30, CorrMonth = Month-1
>
> If "Day"-"DaysDead" = -31 through -60, CorrMonth = Month-2
>
> Otherwise, CorrMonth = Month

In the event there was no bird found at given turbine on a given day, in which case "DaysDead" is 'NA', I want "CorrMonth" = "Month" as well. I know, or think I know, that I can't apply an if statement to an entire column in an R data frame, so I made the vector "dead" used below.

Here is the code I'm using so far:

---

```
dead <- Day - DaysDead
if(dead<=-1&dead>=-30){AvianFatalities$CorrMonth <- AvianFatalities$Month-1}
else
{if(dead<=-30&dead>-60){AvianFatalities$CorrMonth <- AvianFatalities$Month-2}
  else
{AvianFatalities$CorrMonth <- AvianFatalities$Month}}
```

Which gives me the following errors:

```
> if(dead<=-1&dead>=-30){AvianFatalities$CorrMonth <- AvianFatalities$Month-1}
Error in if (dead <= -1 & dead >= -30) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In if (dead <= -1 & dead >= -30) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> else
Error: unexpected 'else' in "else"
> {if(dead<=-30&dead>-60){AvianFatalities$CorrMonth <- AvianFatalities$Month-2}
+  else
+  {AvianFatalities$CorrMonth <- AvianFatalities$Month}}
Error in if (dead <= -30 & dead > -60) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In if (dead <= -30 & dead > -60) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I tried correcting one error using the following:

```
record <- dead[which[dead!='NA']]

for(i in record){
if(dead<=-1&dead>=-30){AvianFatalities$CorrMonth <- AvianFatalities$Month-1}
else
{if(dead<=-30&dead>-60){AvianFatalities$CorrMonth <- AvianFatalities$Month-2}
  else
{AvianFatalities$CorrMonth <- AvianFatalities$Month}}
}
```

And got the following:

```
> record <- dead[which[dead!='NA']]
Error in which[dead != "NA"] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

I don't know how else to rectify the errors I'm getting in trying to apply this statement to my dataset. Any suggestions would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: you don't need a complicated loop. here's an example to play with: `\`colnames<-\`(cbind(dead <- 0:-70, month <- sample(1:12, length(dead), replace = TRUE), month - (1 * dead %in% -1:-30) - (2 * dead %in% -31:-60)), c('dead','month','corr_month'))`

Comment: Either use 'cut' or use 'findInterval'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create data.

```
x <- data.frame(day = c(15,5,20,12),
                daysdead = c(10,15,55,NA),
                month = c(6,7,9,11),
                carcasses = c(14,1,7,0))
```

You want vectorized if/else, so you should use the ifelse function:

```
x$CorrMonth <- x$month
x$CorrMonth <- ifelse(-1 >= (x$day - x$daysdead) & 
                      (x$day - x$daysdead) >= -30,
                      x$CorrMonth - 1, x$CorrMonth)

x$CorrMonth <- ifelse(-31 >= (x$day - x$daysdead) &
                       (x$day - x$daysdead) >= -60,
                      x$CorrMonth - 2, x$CorrMonth)
x$CorrMonth[is.na(x$CorrMonth)] <- x$month[is.na(x$CorrMonth)]                

>     x
  day daysdead month carcasses CorrMonth
1  15       10     6        14         6
2   5       15     7         1         6
3  20       55     9         7         7
4  12       NA    11         0        11
```